# Display Title/Description/Caption of custom images on homepage

Tags: images

I want to display the Title/Description/Caption of custom images on my homepage, here is the current code in functions.php file that only displays the image:

```
<div class="partners-logoarea">
                <?php
                    for ( $count = 1; $count <= 6; $count++ ) {

                        $logo = get_theme_mod( 'unicon_lite_our_partners_logo_'.$count );

                ?>

                    <div class="partners_<?php echo $count; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url($logo); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_html__('Partner Logo', 'unicon-lite'); ?>" /><br/>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

What code do I need to add to display each images Title/Description/Caption?

Comment: Hi Hollie, welcome to stack.  I think you've started perhaps in the wrong place.   The code above is specifically for the logo, which would not typically have Title/Description/Caption.  I imagine you are looking to display this info for other images that have been loaded to the home page?    Usually one adds them via the page editor and can then see the captions (displaying the captions is std wp, most themes would do it.   Please edit your home page via the page editor, play with adding images with captions.  Also explore wordpress galleries of images.

Comment: This is actually not the logo but partner logos that are on the homepage and are added via the WP Customizer. When I upload the logos within the Customizer, I can add the Title/Description/Caption of the images, and now I just want to display that information under each Partner Logo. What extra code do I need to add to the functions.php file to achieve that?

Comment: IMHO this the hard way.  Also using the theme mods locks you in to that theme.  Home page logo display will break if you change themes.   It won't break if you used standard wp image functions like gallery.    To continue using the theme mods, you have to either ask theme support for info, or dig into the theme code to find out if they have also stored the image id somewhere, so that you can access the meta data (caption etc).  WP does not expect to be looking for image data by url, it expects to do it via id.  See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata

Comment: The standard wp options are there and they work without any coding.  In  theme_mods you may also find that you need to tweak the css a little - since they clearly were not expecting to have captions.

Comment: The only other way, you might be able to do it is IF the theme customiser has stored the uploaded theme mods as attachments to the home page, then you could write code to get the attachments which will give you the id's and the urls, you could then match the urls (in case there are non-partner logos also attached) & then you can access the metadata/caption via the id. Either way  think your best bet is to ask the theme support people if perhaps they have also stored the id of the image so you can fetch the caption efficiently (or use std wp)